# Strange noise in analog laser pulse detection circuit

Tags: photodiode, reverse-engineering, laser

I have a laser radiation detection and amplification circuit board. Its schematic is not available due to property restrictions. I made an attempt to analyse and reverse engineer the board.

I reproduced the schematic shown below and tried to simulate its behavior on LTSPice. As expected, the  result was different from what was anticipated.

[image]

I fired laser radiation, having a pulse-width of 60 ns, on the photodiode.  The output before comparator LTC6754 is as shown below.

[image]

If I reduce the radiation on the diode, the output waveform appears more distorted. Would it be possible to improve the shape of the output pulse, as shown below, by carrying out some minor circuit modifications?

My aim is to obtain undistorted output with a pulse width of 30 ns minimum.

[image]

Comment: The circuit you are reverse engineering is oscillating or a different circuit? Probably the feedback capacitance is wrong on the transimpedance amplifier. Try a adjusting the value of the 1.6pF cap and see if slightly different values improve stability.

Comment: Without photographs showing *in detail* how the circuit is assembled and how you're probing it, the only assumptions I can make are: 1. Probing technique is incorrect. 2. Assembly technique is incorrect. Potentially also 3. The light source is not producing the pulse you think. Use an optical probe to confirm.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica i have put a small jumper cable at capacitor, its then latched to a 500MHz oscilloscope probe.nothing special its a regular setup, the laser source is correct its i verified with other appraratus like resistor drop

Comment: @user1850479 the simulation result is ok for the capcitance, i shall try to increase the cap value and check

Comment: What is your power source?

Comment: Your first graph looks like your amplifier might have saturated. If so, decrease the feedback resistor (half, quarter) and increase the feedback capacitor (double, quad) and try again. You may also try to double the opa699 amplification and further reduce the TIA's amplification a bit.